# «Подняться с инвалидного кресла»

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

*Подняться **с** инвалидного кресла.*

Верно ли употреблён предлог?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**подняться**
2. Встать, переменить лежачее или сидячее положение на стоячее.
*Рано подняться **с постели**. Подняться **со стула**. Хозяин поднялся навстречу гостю* (встречая, встал).
[**Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949-1992**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/166250/%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%94%D0%9D%D0%AF%D0%A2%D0%AC%D0%A1%D0%AF)

*Он с трудом **поднялся с кресла** у камина, где грел свои скованные подагрой ноги.*
Эмиль Золя. Радость жизни

*Он **поднялся с кресла** (то же сделал и финдиректор) и отступил от стола на шаг, сжимая в руках портфель.*
М. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита

*С этими словами хозяин дома с очевидной лёгкостью **поднялся с инвалидного кресла** и, сделав несколько шагов, спокойно опустился на стул рядом с гостями.*
А. Орлов. Основной рубеж

*Родислав нехотя **поднялся с удобного вращающегося кресла** с высокой спинкой и подошел к лежащей на полке с книгами трубке.*
А. Маринина. Ад

Употребление предлога "с" правильно: подняться с кресла (с дивана, со стула, со скамейки, с кровати).

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки нет, однако **нет** здесь и **единственно правильного** варианта. Не действуют строгие закономерности, которые связывали бы прямой и обратный предлоги (на->c, в->из): по статистике "нацкорпуса" в **9/10** случаев говорят "опустился **в кресло**" (а не "на кресло"), хотя при этом в **2/3** случаев говорят "поднялся **с кресла**" (а не "**из кресла**"; но второе - более современная тенденция, если дифференцировать усреднённую статистику, и она *ближе к логике* употребления прямого и обратного предлогов). Что касается пребывания **в кресле**, то в **9/10** случаев сидят именно "**в**" нём (хотя **на** стуле) - если, конечно, речь идёт не о кошке и не о сидении на подлокотнике. Это может объяснить современную противоположную тенденцию, которая делает вполне допустимым вариант "**подниматься из кресла**" - его  можно встретить во множестве современных литературных произведений, например:

> Месье Гишар в чудовищном волнении **поднялся из кресла** и прошелся по
> комнате…
>
> *(Дина Рубина. Русская канарейка. Блудный сын /2014/)*

По-видимому, на выбор может влиять контекст: если отвлечься от того, каким образом поднявшийся сидел в кресле (уютно устроившись между подлокотниками и т. п.), то вариант с предлогом "с" будет акцентировать как бы "**подъём с уровня** кресла" (возможно, традиционные предпочтения с этим и связаны); кроме того, если конструкция кресел условна (то, что на стадионах иногда креслами называют, не имеет подлокотников), то сидят именно "на" них, и выражение "*повскакивали с кресел*" уместнее (в нём ещё и "массовость" - не важно, кто как и даже на чём сидел), и т. д.